# pandas groupby to nested json -- dont want calculated fields

Tags: python, json, d3.js, pandas

I'm working on a d3.js graphic.  My data is in a huge multitab .xls. I have to grab data from each tab, so I decided to dump it all in pandas and export some .json.

original data, spread across many tabs:

```
demography, area, state, month, rate
over 65,   region2, GA, May, 23
over 65,  region2, AL, May, 25
NaN,  random_odd_data, mistake, error
18-65, region2, GA, 77
18-65, region2, AL, 75
```

now, put in pandas, merged and cleaned up:

```
     demography area     state  month rate
0    over 65    region2  GA     May   23
1    over 65    region2  AL     May   25
2    18-65      region2  GA     May   50
3    18-65      region2  AL     May   55
```

now, group it

```
group = df.groupby(['state', 'demography'])
```

yields

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x106939610>
```

trying this:

```
group = df.groupby(['state', 'demography']).count()
```

yields something almost correct, except I don't want to count anything, I just want "rate"

```
state    demography  area   month  rate
AL       over 65     1      1      1
         18-65       1      1      1
GA       over 65     1      1      1
         18-65       1      1      1
```

sure enough, this only exports "1" for every value, lol:

```
group.reset_index().to_json("myjson2.json", orient="index")
```

dang I am almost there, how do I export it so each state is a parent?

```
[
    {
        "state": "Alabama",
        "over 65": 25,
        "18-65": 50

    },
    {
        "state": "Georgia",
        "over 65": 23,
        "18-65": 55
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The count method counts the number of non-NaN entries for each group in each column, hence why they're all 1 here (each group is size 1, there are no-NaNs).
*(I can't find a specific link, but it is mentioned in [the groupby docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).)*

---

I think what you actually want is a [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: res = df.pivot_table('rate', 'state', 'demography')

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
demography  18-65  over65
state
AL             55      25
GA             50      23
```

I think you're looking for `orient='records'` (you need to `reset_index` first though):

```
In [13]: res.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
Out[13]: '[{"state":"AL","18-65":55,"over65":25},{"state":"GA","18-65":50,"over65":23}]'
```

Comment: Whoo hoo! It is like Excel, only cool.  One add - for whatever reason it saw 'rate' as type object, not float. It gave me error "no numeric types to aggregate". So I hadda convert it to float:  df.convert_objects('rate', convert_numeric=True)